# Halftone effect: gridded points inside polygon with QGIS Geometry Generator

Tags: qgis, symbology, expression, geometry-generator, point-creation

I am trying to create smooth looking polygons by gridded points in QGIS (2.18.16), with a fading effect towards the boundary of the polygons (halftone effect).

By using the 'fillGrid' function from [@Rob J](https://impermanent.io/2017/05/05/generative-pseudo-random-polygon-fill-patterns-in-qgis/) (Currently the  Error 526), I managed to create gridded point pattern in Geometry Generator.

Now I would like to add a size decrease of the point marker towards the boundary of each polygon starting from a maximum size (e.g. 2 mm) to a minimum size (0 mm). What is the best way to do this? Maybe there is a faster way by  using the standard 'point pattern' option as symbol layer type?

Example image demonstrates the desired effect inside each polygon.

[image: Halftone effect inside polygon]

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/282290/edit) your question to include some screenshots of what you have? :)

Comment: Hope this helps! The code is exactly as in the link, let me know if I should insert this code here too :)

Comment: I suggest adding a field to the points layer that calculates the distance between that point and the centroid of the polygon. Then base the size of the point on that field.

Comment: My previous comment was based on the points being in a separate layer. I don't think you can do a distance calculation using a generated geometry.

Comment: Thanks @csk for the option. I might consider this for now, but I would still prefer to know whether it is possible using geometry generator.

Answer (score 4):

You can fill your polygon with regularily spaced points using this expression with geometry generator. Points are spaced 20 km (20000m, change this at the end of line 4 and 10 if needed).  Be sure to have the data in a projected CRS with units in meters to get correctly spaced points.

```
 intersection (
     collect_geometries(
         array_foreach (
             generate_series(0,y_max($geometry)-ymin($geometry),20000),
             with_variable (
                 'ydist',
                 @element, 
                 collect_geometries(
                     array_foreach(
                     generate_series(0,x_max($geometry)-x_min($geometry),20000),
                         project (
                             make_point (x_min($geometry),y_min($geometry)+@ydist),
                             @element,
                             radians(90)
                         )
                     )
                 )
             )
         )
     ),
     $geometry
 )
```

[image]

However, you can't individually set the size of each point as you still deal with just one single (multipart) feature - so you can only set the size for all dots at once. To solve this, use the same expression as above with [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) to turn these points to actual (multipart) geometries. Convert the resulting layer to single parts using [Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts).

Now you can individually style each point separately. Set a data driven override for the size of the symbol and choose assistant:

[image]

Now you can make what @CSK proposed: calculate the length from each point to the centroid of the polygon shape and divide 1 with this value (the get shrinking size with increasing distance). For this, you can use the following expression. Be aware: you could insert it directly to the `source` field, but depending on how many points you have, rendering will get very slow and you even risk QGIS crashing. So it's better to create this value as an attribute called `size` using Field calculator. Whatever option you use, the expression remains the same (replace `countries` with the name of the polygon layer containing the country shapes and adapt the multiplication factor `*10` at the end to get reasonable numbers):

```
1 / length (
    make_line (
        $geometry, 
        centroid (
            array_first(
                overlay_within(
                    'countries', 
                    $geometry
                )
            )
        )
    )
)*10
```

Now set the calculated `size` field as source in the assistant, then load values for `Values from/to` (double arrow icon) and set `Size from/To`. Apply a transformation curve if needed and experiment with `Scale method/Exponent` to get optimal results:

[image]